# OpenGL Aspect Ratio Issue

Tags: opengl

I am using Qt + OpenGl for 2D rendering.
I am a beginner at OpenGL and for the life of me i am not able to figure out this aspect ratio issue. Everytime i think i have understood glOrtho and gViewPort, but very next time i am into another issue with them. While if coordinates are symmetric like between -1 and 1, my code works else it doesn't. I really want to get through these for once and all. All the suggestions i have searched and applied have gone fruitless for me.

**My Problem Statement:**

I am rendering a square and a triangle and i switch between them with keystroke "R". I am also zooming in and out. While square is maintaining aspect ratio, triangle is not. Coordinates for shapes are:

Square: (-10, -250), (500, -250), (500, -260), (-10, -260);

Triangle: (250, 0), (310, 0), (280, 30)

Basically I am not able to render above triangle. Here is code for same:

**My Code**

```
#include <QtGui/QMouseEvent>
#include <qdebug.h>
#include "GLWidget.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "qgl.h"
#include "qimage.h"

GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent)
{
    setMouseTracking(true);
}

void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
    glEnable( GL_POINT_SMOOTH ); // For Circular Points
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    canvas_width = (double)w;
    canvas_height = (double)h;
    aspect_ratio = canvas_width/canvas_height;

    left_plane  = 250;
    right_plane = 310;
    bottom_plane  = 0;
    top_plane  = 60;
    z_near_plane = 1;
    z_far_plane  = -1;

    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    if( canvas_width > canvas_height ){ 
        glOrtho(left_plane*aspect_ratio, right_plane*aspect_ratio, bottom_plane, top_plane, z_near_plane, z_far_plane);
    }else{
        glOrtho(left_plane, right_plane, bottom_plane/aspect_ratio, top_plane/aspect_ratio, z_near_plane, z_far_plane);
    }

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1,0,0); // red

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        //glVertex2f(-30,0);
        //glVertex2f(30,0);
        //glVertex2f(0,60);
        glVertex2f(250,0);
        glVertex2f(310,0);
        glVertex2f(280,60);
    glEnd();
}
```

I do not see any traingle because left_plane*aspect_ratio clips my drawing (250 is minimum X, 250*1.4 > 310, 310 is maximum X).

I hope i have made myself clear.

I will try to place images as well (i guess i will have to upload images to some other site and link them here?).

Comment: 1. You're using glOrtho() in at least five places. Apart from making the question harder to answer, this coding style is not recommended. You should refactor this into one function which takes width and height of the viewport as its input. 2. Your question is quite long. :) It's not clear what works and what doesn't. I suggest you back up your source directory, delete everything that's already working or not relevant to the question and post what's left.

Comment: I apologize for making it look clumsy. I have sorted it out. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: You are using deprecated functions, just as information for you.

Comment: I agree Felix, i am using deprectaed stuff of glBegin and glEnd. I am learning retained mode version as well, but this thing was on my head and so i used immediate mode for immediately giving results. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the bounding box (the values assigned to left/right/top/bottom_plane) doesn't have the same aspect ratio as the viewport. If you have the bounding box for the object, you need to find viewport coordinates with the correct aspect ratio (w/h). The viewport needs to be both centered on the bounding box center, and be big enough to fit the bounding box. But the aspect ratio of the viewport has nothing to do with the size of the bounding box.

In general you have a 3D bounding box (8 corner points). You would project each corner onto the screen, then use min/max to get a rectangle that needs to be centered on screen. You then check the aspect ratio ar = wr/hr of that rectangle against the aspect ratio of the viewport a=w/r. If a < ar, you need to fit wr to w, otherwise fit hr to h.

```
void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
  // First set up the projection.
  double canvas_width = (double)w;
  double canvas_height = (double)h;
  double a = canvas_width / canvas_height;

  glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho(-a, +a, -1, +1, -1, +1);

  // Now set up the view matrix.
  double leftBoundingRectangle  = 250;
  double rightBoundingRectangle = 310;
  double bottomBoundingRectangle  = 0;
  double topBoundingRectangle  = 60;

  double widthBoundingRectangle = rightBoundingRectangle - leftBoundingRectangle;
  double heightBoundingRectangle = topBoundingRectangle - bottomBoundingRectangle;

  double ar = widthBoundingRectangle / heightBoundingRectangle;

  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();

  // Center on bounding rectangle center.
  double tx = (leftBoundingRectangle + rightBoundingRectangle)/2.0, ty = (topBoundingRectangle + bottomBoundingRectangle)/2.0;
  glTranslated(tx, ty, 0.0); // or is it -tx, -ty?

  // Scale to fit bounding box.
  double s;
  if (ar > a)
  {
    s = ... // sorry, but you have to figure this one out for yourself. :)
  }
  else
  {
    s = ...
  }
  glScaled(s,s,s);
}
```

Comment: Thx for replying Andreas. I think i will have to unlearn many things. Basically you are saying that to maintain aspect ratio one has to change ViewPort? While all this while i was changing clipping planes by glOrtho...which obviously didn't work in this case but worked for other symmetric cases (like in above case if triangle coordinates were (-30, 0), (30, 0), (0,60)...changing glOrtho works. If you notice aspect ratio of triangle between -30 and +30 is 1 and is same as triangle between 250 and 310. Oh there is character limit to comments, i will elaborate my doubts on your reply in post.Thx.

Comment: I don't think modifying ViewPort is going to help. Viewport implies, where to draw on window. Though modifying it will help in centering my bounding box at the viewport. But to keep aspect ratio, i am sure one has to modify clipping planes with glOrtho. What you say?

Comment: No, glViewport(0,0,w,h) is fine. What I meant is that you should call glOrtho(l,r,t,b) with different values. But they need to have the same aspect ratio: (r-l)/(b-t) == w/h.

Comment: Thx for replying Andreas. But that is what i did in above code. glOrtho(l*ar, r*ar, b, t). So aspect ratio for triangle = (r-l)*ar/(t-b). And (r-l) = (t-b). And ar = aspect ratio of Viewport. You see issue is l*ar > x_min and r*ar > x_max. So i am viewing somewhere else while drawing somewhere else :)

Comment: I've edited the answer. Hope this helps. Try reading up on the OpenGL matrix stack (model view projection). You might want to look at glut. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Andreas for posting code. I see that you are using scaling function to achieve same aspect ratio. Cool...Your previous comment that viewport and bounding box aspect ratio should be same has helped me some and i am able to view triangle correctly. I will use your suggestion as well regarding scaling and post my replies for both approaches soon. Thanks a lot again for your time, help, suggestions and guidance. Appreciate that :)